# PHP Find keys in one array that exist as values in another array, and pull back the value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, the first has keys, which exist as values in the second array.
I'd like to identify the keys in the first array, that exist as values in the second array. And in the second array, i'd like to change the value (that is the key in the first array) to the value of the key in the first array.

**First Array**

```
Array
(
    **[sequence]** => 2344
    **[imbarcode]** => DTTDTADDFDTADTDTAAATDFAFTTFDDAAFFFTTAADFADDDFATADADDFATDDDTDFTDFD
    **[first]** => Lisa A
    **[last]** => Dedrick
    **[address]** => 4019 Nightington Dr
    **[city]** => Province
    **[st]** => PA
    **[zip]** => 10059-1702
)
```

**Second Array**

```
Array
(
    [deleted_on] => 
    [universe_id] => 1
    [street] => **address**
    [city] => **city**
    [state] => **st**
    [zip] => **zip**
    [check_digit] => **sequence**
    [carrier_route] => **imbarcode**
)
```

**Desired result**

```
Array
(
    [deleted_on] => 
    [universe_id] => 1
    [street] => **4019 Nightington Dr**
    [city] => **Province**
    [state] => **PA**
    [zip] => **10059-1702**
    [check_digit] => **2334**
    [carrier_route] => **DTTDTADDFDTADTDTAAATDFAFTTFDDAAFFFTTAADFADDDFATADADDFATDDDTDFTDFD**
)
```

This could be done with multiple foreachs, but i'd like to find a less expensive way to do this as there could be a massively large number of arrays we're essentially mapping.

**Full story**

The first array, is one of what could be thousands (from a csv). So if we have 50,000 line items in the csv, we'll have 49,999 arrays. The second array, will always have four arrays (they'll correlate to a database). The end result, (with the above csv example) should have one mass array, with 4 sub arrays, where each sub-array has 49,999 arrays within it.

Not very efficient with PHP however, it's what I am limited to currently.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Here is what I have that atleast maps the values (does not retain the other values I need)

```
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($csv as $k => $v) {
                foreach ($val as $dk => $dv) {
                    foreach ($v as $ck => $cv) {
                        if ($dv == $ck) {
                            $res[$dk] = $cv;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $result[$key][] = $res;
            }
        }
        $this->out(print_r($result,true));
```

I don't want to foreach this many times.

SOLVED.

Solution

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($csv as $ck => $cv) {
        $result[$key][] = str_replace(array_keys($cv), $cv, $val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the `**` to highlight things as `print_r` would not display it that way, rather `[**address**]`.  But `str_replace` supports arrays, so search the second array for the keys in the first array and replace with the values of the first array:

```
$result = str_replace(array_keys($first), $first, $second);
```

Comment: You are fantastic, and your solution works perfectly. Here is the code:               foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                foreach ($csv as $ck => $cv) {
                    $result[$key][] = str_replace(array_keys($cv), $cv, $val);
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

Only one foreach is needed.

```
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
    $arr2[$key] = $arr1[$value] ?? $value;
}
```

Comment: This would work sure, but we're already inside of two foreachs (one for each array) and I really don't want to nest further. Plus we need to retain all of the other values.

Comment: I understand the _retain all of the other values_, which my answer does, but without code we can't tell why you are in two `foreach`s already and if something can be done there.